# What logical principle allows you to conclude from “A or B; B;”, “not A”?

Tags: logic

Is the following example a valid argument:

```
Either Your hair is short or long.
It is long.
Therefore it is not short.
```

This is the form of the argument:
Either P or Q.
P.
So not Q.

Comment: No, it is not. In logic "or" is *inclusive*, i.e. it is *true* when at least one of the disjuncts is *true*.

Comment: This is the form of the argument:                                                            Either P or Q.
P.
So not Q.

Comment: Are you sure that " Either P or Q. P. So not Q" is not valid?

Comment: "Either Napoleon is French or it is a male" is *true* and also "Napoleon is French" is *true*. Then, we have to conclude that "Napoleon is not a male" ????

Comment: What about the following: > Either P or Q. P. Therefore P. I believe this would be a valid argument.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: "Either / or" is usually read as "one is true and the other is not", different from plain "or".

Comment: The symbolic form is valid because P is taken to be unambiguous.  But 'short' is ambiguous, so the form does not fit the example.

Comment: This is the recurrent question type (RQT) [“Is X valid?”](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5658/recurrent-question-type-rqt-is-x-valid). I invite anyone to discuss or analyze how such questions may be improved at the link provided.

Comment: I'm with @MauroALLEGRANZA on this one. In English, even when you use 'either', it suggests the exclusive reading but it does not force it. There is nothing contradictory about, "either A or B and maybe both". So the 'or' is ambiguous. It is just an unfortunately gap in English that we don't have different words for inclusive and exclusive or.

Answer (score 5):

I disagree with the answers above.

[Either / or corresponds unequivocally, in English, to an exclusive or (XOR).](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/either-or) The XOR function returns true only if P and Q have opposite values (T/F, F/T).

Hence the statement "You hair is not short" returns true.

The problem was merely in the translation into formula, becaused it used "OR"; but it is obvious from the question that it should have been formulated as XOR.

Comment: Agree. In plain English, the word "Either" means only one of the two possibilities can be true.  As opposed to "your hair is short or long" which would be true if my hair was short and also if it were long.

Comment: A question about language : what is in "plain English" the *negation* of "Either ... or ..." ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Sorry for the late answer:  "Neither A nor B", i.e. not A and not B. Putting an "n" in front of "either" and "or" kind of makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

The original example: Either Your hair is short or long. It is long. Therefore it is not short.

Assumptions. (1) Short is defined as 'not long' (S= ~L) and vice versa. One term is the negation of the other. (2) 'Either/or' means either one or the other, but not both.

On those assumptions the example is valid reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to apply exclusive 'or' to quantities due to the sorites paradox (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorites_paradox) -- 'Either a collection of grains is a heap, or it is not' is simply not true.  Likewise 'Either a hair is long or short' is also simply not true.

Further, there is a problem with collective application of properties -- not all of the individual hairs are necessarily of comparable length, so it might be meaningless to declare 'your hair' long or short.  If you have 'bangs', you still have long hair, but some of your hair is short.

There is nothing wrong with the logic, but the premise oversimplifies the semantics of measurement and collective reference.

So this could be considered valid but not sound, or it could be considered invalid because some of the statements involved have ambiguous truth values, and valid arguments only work on binary truth, depending upon how much semantics you consider part of the form.

Answer (score 1):

English has some clarity problems as a language in that we do not have separate terms for **"inclusive or"** and **"exclusive or"** in our everyday language.

The closest we have is something along the lines of the phrases "A or B, or both" and "A or B, but NOT both."

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a slightly different take on this than the other answers: the first premise is ambiguous, so there's not enough information to determine if it's valid or not.

As others have indicated, the main issue here is "translating" this sentence into its equivalent logic statements.

Logically,

```
A \/ B
A
Therefore, ~B
```

is very clearly invalid because "or" ( / ) is inclusive (i.e. "*at least* one of these statements is true) in formal logic.

In spoken language, however, people will often use the word "or" to denote "exclusive or" (i.e. *exactly one* of these statements is true). In fact, it would probably seem rather odd (and possibly misleading) if someone used it in some other sense. If we translate this sentence in that way, this would become

```
A xor B
A
Therefore, ~B
```

which is perfectly valid.

Thus, whether this is "valid" or not really depends on the context of the original argument. If it's from some kind of "ordinary" spoken language, they probably meant "xor," in which case it's valid. However, if it's from some kind of more rigorous text or context it probably means "inclusive or," in which case it's clearly not valid.

Comment: It is ambiguous, but not because of the 'or'.  Either X or Y is rather unambiguous in English.

Answer (score 0):

Logically, in the usual, contemporary sense of the word where we do not take into account semantics and judgement - but merely it's form - it's a *valid* argument - as pointed out by Mark Andrews answer

However, taking one step away, we can *judge* that it has produced no *new* information, so though valid it's not useful.

Judgement, is a part of philosophical logic, if not formal logic; and is key to reflection as pointed out by Arendt when discussing Kants political philosophy.

Comment: By that standard, valid arguments are almost always not useful.  All strict logic is a tautology at some point.

Comment: @jobermark: that wasn't what I was driving at; I'm merely pointing out - though that's probably not clear from my brief answer - that the conclusion is simply one the premises:one of the premises is, 'it is long', and the conclusion is, 'it is long'.

Comment: Whereas in a syllogism such as 'Socrates is himan, humans are mortal; therefore Socrates is mortal', produces a conclusion that isn't one of the premises - it's a new sentence; it's that sense of new that I'm talking about.

Comment: The conclusion, as I see it, is likely to often be false, due to the sorites paradox.  There is new information here, because it is likely, under realistic circumstances to disagree with reality in a way in which the given information would not.  Information-theoretically, these are not equivalent, one is iffy, the other is not.